# Shortcut for Direction Keys -- To keep hands on QWERTY end of the keyboard

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a lot of Excel and finally got myself used to the ThinkPad pointer whereby I no longer need to take my hands off the keyboard for scrolling.

But now I need to take my right hand off the keyboard when I wish to use the directional up, down, right, left keys in Excel cells.

I tried the solution of using the smallest finger on my right hand to hit these directional keys, but this is not very accurate or fast.

Is there some key combination (using Alt or Control or something) that I can use to move around in Excel from the main QWERTY keyboard?

Comment: Do you have *Function* keys at the top of your keyboard ?

Comment: by default `Tab` will move right, `Shift+Tab` left, `Enter` Down and `Shift+Enter` will move up. does this satisfy you?